# Mod_rewrite working on http but not https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a mod_rewrite that works fine on http, but not on https.

Some answers on stack overflow to similar questions suggest adding RewriteBase /, but I already have that.

I'm hosted on godaddy on a shared server. I have contacted godaddy 3 times and they say they can't do anything.

Here is an example of the rewrite:

URL Without Rewrite:
https://www.funded.today/stats/?p=bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Mod_Rewrite URL:
https://www.funded.today/stats/iga/bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

My htaccess file is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?funded\.today$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.funded.today/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^stats/(.*)/(.*)$ /stats/?p=$2 [P,QSA]

# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stats/(.*)/(.*)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help or ideas on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using the `P` (mod_proxy) flag? `RewriteEngine On` should only appear once in the file (at the top). The same for `RewriteBase` (the last one wins). The `Options` directive should also be at the top (or it's not required). Your canonical redirect is not correct.

Comment: "Some answers on stack overflow ... suggest adding RewriteBase /" - have you asked yourself why? From what you have posted, the `RewriteBase` directive does not seem to be required at all. The `RewriteBase` directive is only required if you have relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule`.